# Null data on DateTime from database

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, null

I've been through the various answers here with this one already, but none give an answer that actually works.
The core issue (obviously) is that DateTime hasn't any concept of NULL, so the usual

```
string dateValue = myReader.IsDBNull (4) ? null : myReader.GetDateTime(4) ;
```

doesn't work.

I've tried

```
DateTime? nextDue = myReader.GetDateTime(3) == DBNull.Value ? null : (DateTime?)myReader.GetDateTime (3) ;
```

but that gives

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'System.DBNull'
```

Changing to

```
DateTime? nextDue = myReader.GetDateTime(3) = DBNull.Value ? null : (DateTime?)myReader.GetDateTime (3) ;
```

produces

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'bool'
```

I ended up changing the SQL to not output NULL values, but I'd still like to crack this one, as it will be useful elsewhere

Comment: Your final code snippet is using `=` instead of `==`

Comment: Your message says about converting "to 'bool'"; your code shows you querying a `DateTime`, and assigning to a `string`. Has some code here become even more confused in the "make it suitable to post" step?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
DateTime? nextDue = myReader.IsDbNull(3) ? null : (DateTime?) myReader.GetDateTime (3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly Your syntax here:

```
DateTime? nextDue = myReader.GetDateTime(3) = DBNull.Value ? null : (DateTime?)myReader.GetDateTime (3) ;
```

id wrong.  Should be:

```
DateTime? nextDue = myReader.GetDateTime(3) == DBNull.Value ? null : (DateTime?)myReader.GetDateTime (3) ;
```

Secondly you could use:

```
DateTime? nextDue = myReader.IsDBNull(3) ? null : (DateTime?)myReader.GetDateTime (3) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
DateTime? nextDue;
if (myReader.GetDateTime(3) == DBNull.Value)
    nextDue = myReader.GetDateTime(3);
else
    nextDue = null;
```

Alternatively:

```
DateTime? nextDue;
if (myReader.IsDBNull(3))
    nextDue = myReader.GetDateTime(3);
else
    nextDue = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `null` to `DateTime?`:

```
DateTime? nextDue = myReader.IsDBNull(3) ? 
    null as DateTime? : 
    (DateTime?)myReader.GetDateTime (3)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  DateTime? nextDue = myReader.GetValue(3) == DBNull.Value ? null : (DateTime?)myReader.GetDateTime (3);
```

Comment: I suspect that if column 3 ISN'T null, this will blow up.

Comment: Because column 3 isn't a string: it's a date, when it isn't null. Casting it to a string (which is what GetString will do) will cause an error.